# Python opencv - How can I speed up my movie

Tags: python, opencv, video-editing

I vould like to speed up my movie by 2 times meaning that every frame vould appear for half of it's original time. My code currently does not do this and I do not understand why. The error I am currently getting is in this line **(**if cv2.waitKey(0.5) & 0xFF == ord('q'):**)** and the error is: **TypeError: Argument 'delay' is required to be an integer**

Here is my code:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

while cap.isOpened():

    ret,frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('video', frame)
   
    if cv2.waitKey(0.5) & 0xFF == ord('q'): # if I understand correctly the number in the bracket which is currently 0.5 shoud speed up the proces but it doesn't
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: please always post full error traces.

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.waitKey(0.5)` expects an integer (milliseconds), and you provide a float (probably thinking in seconds).

See [the doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7)

> The function waitKey waits for a key event infinitely (when delay≤0 )
> or for delay milliseconds, ...

You should input `500` instead of `0.5`.

---

That will fix your error, but will not speed up your video.
To speed up the video you should [get the frame rate](https://learnopencv.com/how-to-find-frame-rate-or-frames-per-second-fps-in-opencv-python-cpp/) and play in double that rate.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `waitkey` only takes input as int type. That int number represents for ms per frame, and increase that number will slow down not speed up your video.

Secondly, I found a similar question in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58264325/python-opencv-control-increase-decrease-the-video-playback-speed-as-custom), hope this will help you.